# TSQL - Extract text between two words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did find some info on the site but I am unable to make it work correctly. I have a text field [User] that contains USER: John.Smith SessionId: {There is a space after User: and one after the name}

Everything I tried will either remove the first section or the last one, none remove both. Or will give me this message Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

I want to have the name John.Smith extracted from that field.
If possible I do not want to declare any tables.

Thanks

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `replace()`?

```
select replace(replace(col, 'USER: ', ''), ' SessionId:', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If open to a TVF

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](SomeCol,'USER:','SessionId:') B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       John.Smith
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delim1,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
            Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I got SUBSTRING() to work:

```
SUBSTRING(USER, 7,(LEN(USER)-7)-(charindex('SessionId',USERID)))
```

Where:
7 = # of characters in "USERID:"
LEN(User)-7 counts the character length less the 7 from "USERID:"
charindex('SessionId',USERID) gives you the character location where "SessionId" starts